# Publicar APK o Bundle en Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, test, apk

Tengo varias dudas:

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre publicar un .apk o un bundle .aab?

He hecho todo el recorrido:

- Prueba interna
- Alfa cerrado
- Beta abierto
- Producción

Actualmente mi app está en producción y es tan pequeña que no merece la pena pasar por los 4 estados, ¿puedo publicar directamente en producción siempre?

En mi móvil a pesar de subir la versión a producción una y otra vez no aparece el botón de "actualizar", ¿es  normal?, tampoco aparece mi app en la lista de aplicaciones instaladas, colección, beta, etcétera.

Comment: Puedes publicarla directamente a producción, la distribución no es inmediata por eso es que no te aparece en la tienda ya sea para actualizar o instalar por primera vez, debes esperar ya sea minutos o hrs, el tiempo varia. Para que se actualice en tu dispositivo debiste haberla instalado desde la tienda igual la primera vez.

Comment: "En mi móvil a pesar de subir la versión a producción una y otra vez no aparece el botón de " ¿Que cambios realizas en cada actualización de tu apk cuando la subes a producción ?

Comment: Creo entender por qué no aparece le botón de actualizar. Es por haber instalado la app desde Studio en vez de Google Play.